# Vue. A dynamically variable in v-if

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Is there any way to add a variable in a **v-if** statement in my situation?
I have a variable in data `language = 'en'`, a big json with some data in multiple language (it's called **message**).
The message json looks like:

```
"message": {
  "en": 1,
  "es": 2
}
```

and then I want to code like this.

```
<span v-if="message.lang">some data</span>
```

It works this way

```
<span v-if="message.en">some data</span>
```

It doesn't work

```
<span v-if="message[lang]">some data</span>
```

but this way I cannot use the **lang** variable.
Can anyone help me with my problem?

Comment: `message` needs to be an array of objects for that way to work: `"message": [
  {"lang": "en"},
  {"lang": "es"}
]`

Comment: Where/how is your variable `lang` defined? If it is not bound to the Vue component in any way, you will not have access to it.

Comment: one way to solve it can be by using a watcher. create a variable named activeLang, use a watcher on lang (the dynamic variable you are talking about),  change the value of activeLang when the lang variable changes and bind the activeLang variable to v-if

Comment: Users can change lang variable by clicking on buttons like "show this message in English" etc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't change your message object. Simply use the `lang` property as **computed property** that returns a defined property `currentLang="en"`in data and dynamically change that property. For example:

```
 data: {
        currentLang: 'en',
        ...
      }
```

On the respective button click call a method like:

```
onLangChange(event){
this.currentLang = "es";
}
```

So whenever `currentLang` changes its gonna trigger computed of `lang`:

```
 computed: {
    lang: function () {
      return this.currentLang;
    }
  }
```

And then it will update the html accordingly:

```
 <span v-if="message[lang]">some data</span>
```

Comment: The last v-if you have provided is wrong, because this way I will have an error. The "message" json doesn't have 'lang' property. There are, e.g. message.en and message.es

Comment: Yeah it was not meant to be like this message['lang']. I have updated it the moment i saw it. Sorry.

Answer (score 1):

Did you defined the `lang` property in your data ?

```
<template>
  <h1>{{ message[lang] }}</h1>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "HelloWorld",
  data() {
    return {
      lang: 'en',
      message: {
        en: 'foo bar',
        fr: 'machin truc'
      }
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

I think you should have a look at https://github.com/kazupon/vue-i18n

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I am already using i18n.

Yes, I defend lang property in my data.

My problem is that some data I'm fetching from my DB and some of this data has multiple translations, so I wan't to check (with v-if) if those data has the selected language if not then display in "there is no translation".

`<span v-if="message.???">word</span>
<span v-else>There is no translation</span>`

Comment: So the right syntax is `v-if="message[lang]"` if message[lang] is not defined it should work well and be falsy.